# If statement in django not working as expected

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to show the user a list of attributes from objects in my database but only when the name of the object is the same as the group the user is in.
In my code I have this:

```
            {% for page in object_list %}
            {% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
            {% if page.organisation == group.name %}

            {{group.name}} group name
            {{page.organisation}} page
            <li> {{page.page_name}} </li>
            <li> {{page.data_location}} </li>
            <li> {{page.organisation}} </li>

            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

when I run the list items do not show up as if the group name and page organisation variables do not match.
However when I remove the if statement to compare the variables (as they should match with my test data) They show for example {{group.name}} = Abc {{page.organisation}} = Abc

How can I get this list items to show when the two values are the same?

Sample of my data:

```
page{
page.name = "abc"
page.data_location = "http://google.com"
page.organisation = "abc"
}
```

The user in a group called abc

I think it might be an issue with type and exact matches but I can't tell if thats the case when I show group.name and page.organisation.name directly.

Comment: Can you try with a single `=`

Comment: Ill give it a go now :)

Comment: Errors out if you use a single =

Comment: It is probably because either of `page.organisation` or `group.name` are unicode objects. Can you print the type of those elements in your views?

Comment: Is `page.organisation` really a string? Or a `ForeignKey` to an `Organisation` model?

Comment: Doesn't directly solve the issue but filtering the queryset directly would be more efficient: `request.user.groups.filter(name=page.organisation.name)`

Comment: This is what my model looks like:

Comment: class Page(models.Model):
    data_location = models.URLField()
    page_name= models.CharField(max_length=150)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: so yes Daniel hepper its a foreign key, how is best to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to retrieve the `name` (or whatever the property is named) of the `organisation` then: `page.organisation.name == group.name`.

Comment: perfect that solved the issue. Thanks so much Frankie and Daniel

Comment: The above is correct in that you should compare names.  However, the correct way to do this kind of check is in the view itself (prior to rendering the template).  If someone is trying to access a page that they shouldn't be on, you should redirect them away from the page in the `views.py` code.